# flutter: how to use 'await for' to wait for other BLoC event to finish

Tags: flutter, async-await, state, bloc

on screen init, I am loading my data via an externalData_bloc. On the same screen I am also rendering another widget controlled with internalData_bloc for user input which depends on the number of imported records (how many rows are needed). Of course, the rendering is faster than the data load, so I get null rows needed.

I found this nice [question & answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56322631/awaiting-some-results-before-dispatching-an-event-with-flutter-bloc-library), however, I do not get it to work. The solution says

```dart
Future loginProcess() async {
  await for (var result in _userBloc.state) {
    if (result.status == Status.finished) {
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

I am within my repository. In here, I am also storing the external data in a variable. So within the repository class I have my function to get the number of records (`properties` are stored in the repository, and I want to return its length).

```dart
  Future<int> getNoOfProperties(int problem)  async {
    LogicGraphsPStmntBloc bloc = LogicGraphsPStmntBloc();
    Future propertiesLoad() async {
      await for (var s in bloc) {
        if (s == LogicGraphsPStmntLoadSuccess) {
          return;
        }
      }
    }
    propertiesLoad();
    return properties.length;
  }
```

But no matter what I try to put in for `await for (var result in XXXX)` or `if (s.YYY == ZZZ)`, it doesn't work. My understanding is, XXXX needs to be a stream which is why I used `bloc = LogicGraphsPStmntBloc()`. But I guess this creates another instance than the one used in my widgets. `LogicGraphsPStmntBloc` doesn't work either, nor do states. `bloc` at least doesn't throw an error already in the editor, but besides the instance issue, the if statement throws an error, where in cubit.dart `StreamSubscription<State> listen(...` is called with `cancelOnError` . Anyone having some enlightenment?

Answer (score 1):

Bloc uses Stream and has a continuous flow of data. You might want to listen for changes in data instead of a finished task. Using a StreamBuilder is one way of doing this.

```dart
StreamBuilder<User>(
  stream: bloc.userState, // Stream from bloc
  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<State> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      // check if auth status is finished
    }
  }
)
```